# Adding !important within a dynamically written stylesheet for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

I have been experimenting with using javascript to dynamically write stylesheets. In Firefox, one can use the `setProperty` method on the style for the `cssRules` of the `styleSheets`, like...

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style
  .setProperty(propertyName, propertyValue, 'important');
```

...to set the `!important` flag on the style. I have not found an equivalent for this in Internet Explorer (the `setAttribute` method does not have such an option for setting the `!important` flag on a style). Some experimentation found that for exact styles, such as `border-top-width,` I can rewrite the `cssText` string to add the `!important`, but then I discovered that if you individually set all the borders, IE rewrites the actual rule to be a short hand form, so it rewrites to `border-top`, `border-right`, etc., and each gets set, but without the `!important` flag. Further, if I explicitly set it via the short hand form, it **does not** accept a rewrite of the `cssText` to take the `!important` flag.

So the question is, does anyone know of a way, when dynamically writing styles to a `styleSheets` rule, to get IE to consistently set the `!important` flag for that rule?

Thanks for your help,

Scott

Comment: I assume no one has anything to offer on a solution for this (if, indeed there is a solution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spent some more time doing some testing, and have come to the conclusion that my rewrite of the `cssText` ***is*** working to add `!important` to some mysterious internal flag setting of IE, even though the shortened properties that itself rewrites for the `cssText` do not reflect that.

Apparently, neither the `cssText` property (if it is examined after my rewrite to add the `!important`) nor the Microsoft Developer Toolbar examination of the element are showing the fact that the property has an `!important` setting on it. The element is, however, displaying as if my rewrite worked. I tested this by placing an `!important` on the base style for an image border like so:

```
img {border: 3px solid green !important;}
```

Then with javascript I created my styleSheets object and added a rule that was both more specific (using the `id` of the image) and that had its `cssText` rewritten with `!important` after already having set the `style` of the `styleSheets` object by a javascript call for `borderTopColor = red`. I then set the inline style of the element to change the top color to yellow. The results were as I would expect with the `!important` flag. The red wins out, as it is a later (and more specific) call than the original green, and the inline style does not override it. If I remove the rewrite of the`!important` then the color reverts to green, and if I remove green's `!important` the color reverts to yellow.

I also tested this with the green having a higher selector specificity than my javascript written style for the red. That, too, behaved as expected, with green winning out since it now had the higher selector specificity with the competing `!important` of the red declaration.

This was tested on IE8, IE7, and IE6 (yes, it worked there too). While rewriting/setting the `cssText` of the `styleSheets` is not as easy as being able to set it with a straight javascript call on the property, at least it works. The real 'bug' is the fact that neither the `cssText` nor the Developer Toolbar were giving me correct information that an `!important` flag was set on those styles, so if someone were coming behind and examining the site, they may get confused as to why something is happening with the styles (why something that does not seem to be important is acting as if it is).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet here is to write your css so that you don't have to use !important to override styles in the cascade. It sucks, but that's how the IE crumbles.

Comment: The two problems with simply relying on cascade is 1) if there is another !important already in the cascade, or 2) an inline style is set on the element in question. Really, my question is more a case of whether or not anyone knows of some way to set the !important flag in IE that I have yet been able to find.